# How to dynamically add classes to other elements on click with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a exercise where there are 4 different color boxes and 1 main box below them that is blank, when you click on one of the colored boxes, the main box changes to the color of the box you just clicked on. This seems like a piece of cake with jQuery but I don't know how to do this with Angular

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

function angularBoxesCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.mainBoxColor;

  vm.logClass = function(e) {
    var boxColor = e.target.classList[1];
    vm.mainBoxColor = boxColor;
    console.log(vm.mainBoxColor);
  }

}



angular.module('angularBoxes', [])
  .controller('angularBoxesCtrl', [
    angularBoxesCtrl
    ]);


})();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Boxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="angularBoxes">
  <div ng-controller="angularBoxesCtrl as vm" class="boxHolder">
    <div ng-click="vm.logClass($event)" class="box green"></div>
    <div ng-click="vm.logClass($event)" class="box blue"></div>
    <div ng-click="vm.logClass($event)" class="box red"></div>
    <div ng-click="vm.logClass($event)" class="box yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainBox" ng-class></div>

  <!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.boxHolder {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.mainBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: there is an example that basically does this exact thing on the documentation page for ng-class. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I just realized my mistake was not ngClass but not having the mainBox be part of the ngController *facePalm*

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="myStyle={background:'red'}">
  <input type="button" value="Green" ng-click="myStyle={background:'green'}">
  <input type="button" value="Blue" ng-click="myStyle={background:'blue'}">
  <input type="button" value="Yellow" ng-click="myStyle={background:'yellow'}">
  <input type="button" value="Lime" ng-click="myStyle={background:'lime'}">
  <input type="button" value="Magenta" ng-click="myStyle={background:'magenta'}">
  <input type="button" value="Pink" ng-click="myStyle={background:'pink'}">
  <input type="button" value="White" ng-click="myStyle={background:'white'}"> 

  <div ng-style="myStyle" >
    </BR></BR></BR></BR></BR>
    <Center>
    <h1>Hello</BR>
     C-Sharp</BR>
     Corner</BR>
    POST BY: Punit Gajjar
    </H1></center></BR></BR></BR></BR></BR>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<div ng-init="setFromDiv = 'green'" ng-click="setFromDiv = 'green'"class="box green"></div>
<div ng-click="setFromDiv = 'blue'" class="box blue"></div>
<div ng-click="setFromDiv = 'red'" class="box red"></div>
<div ng-click="setFromDiv = 'yellow'" class="box yellow"></div>
<div class="mainBox" ng-class="setFromDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
<div class="mainBox" ng-style="{'background-color': {{myColor}}}"></div>
```

On your button click call function

```
<a ng-click="SetClass($event)" class="green">Make Green</a>

$scope.SetClass = function(obj) {           

        //console.log(obj);            
        // Alert just the data value
        $scope.myColor = obj.target.attributes.class.value;

    }
```

or you can set a variable which contains css like this

```
 $scope.myStyle = {
          "background": obj.target.attributes.class.value;
        };
```

Then use in `ng-style` as usual way.

```
 <div ng-style="myStyle"></div>
```